# How to get multiple objects in list at a point in time

Tags: firebase

I want to provide my users with an API (pointing to my server) that will fetch data from Firebase and return it to them. I want it to be a 'normal' point-in-time request (as opposed to streaming).

My data is 'boxes' within 'projects'. A user can query my API to get all boxes for a project.

My data is normalised, so I will look up the project and get a list of keys of boxes in that project, then go get each box record individually. Once I have them all, I will return the array to the user.

My question: what is the best way to do this?

Here's what I have, and it works. But it feels so hacky.

```
  const projectId = req.params.projectId; // this is passed in by the user in their call to my server.

  const boxes = [];
  let totalBoxCount = 0;
  let fetchedBoxCount = 0;

  const projectBoxesRef = db
    .child('data/projects')
    .child(projectId)
    .child('boxes'); // a list of box keys

  function getBox(boxSnapshot) {
    totalBoxCount++;

    db
      .child('data/boxes') // a list of box objects
      .child(boxSnapshot.key())
      .once('value')
      .then(boxSnapshot => {
        boxes.push(boxSnapshot.val());

        fetchedBoxCount++;

        if (fetchedBoxCount === totalBoxCount) {
          res.json(boxes); // leap of faith that getBox() has been called for all boxes
        }
      });
  }

  projectBoxesRef.on('child_added', getBox);

  // 'value' fires after all initial 'child_added' things are done
  projectBoxesRef.once('value', () => {
    projectBoxesRef.off('child_added', getBox);
  });
```

There are some other questions/answers on separating the initial set of `child_added` objects, and they have influenced my current decision, but they don't seem to relate directly.

Thanks a truck-load for any help.

Update: JavaScript version of Jay's answer below:

```
db
  .child('data/boxes')
  .orderByChild(`projects/${projectId}`)
  .equalTo(true)
  .once('value', boxSnapshot => {
    const result = // some parsing of response

    res.json(result);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be too simple a solution but if you have projects, and each project has boxes

your projects node

```
projects
  project_01
    boxes
      box_id_7: true
      box_id_9: true
      box_id_34: true
  project_37
    boxes
      box_id_7: true
      box_id_14: true
      box_id_42: true
```

and the boxes node

```
boxes
  box_id_7
    name: "a 3D box"
    shape: "Parallelepiped"
    belongs_to_project
       project_01: true
  box_id_14
    name: "I have unequal lenghts"
    shape: "Rhumboid"
    belongs_to_project
       project_37: true
  box_id_34
    name: "Kinda like a box but with rectangles"
    shape: "cuboid"
    belongs_to_project
       project_01: true
```

With that, just one (deep) query on the boxes node will load all of the boxes that belong to project_01, which in this case is box_id_7 and box_id_34.

You could go the the other way and since you know the box id for each project in the projects node, you could do a series of observers to load in each project via it's specific path  /boxes/box_id_7 etc. I like the query better; faster and less bandwidth.

You could expand on this if a box can belong to multiple projects:

```
  box_id_14
    name: "I have unequal lenghts"
    shape: "Rhumboid"
    belongs_to_project
       project_01: true
       project_37: true
```

Now query on the boxes node for all boxes that are part of project_01 will get box_id_7, box_id_14 and box_id_34.

Edit:

Once that structure is in place, use a Deep Query to then get the boxes that belong to the project in question.

For example: suppose you want to craft a [Firebase Deep Query](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-09-24-atomic-writes-and-more.html) to return all boxes where the box's belongs_to_project list contains an item with key "project_37"

```
boxesRef.queryOrderedByChild("belongs_to_project/project_37"
    .queryEqualToValue(true)
    .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        print(snapshot)
})
```

Comment: That sounds good, but what does "one (deep) query" look like?

Comment: @DavidGilbertson There's a great blog post on the firebase website that explains deep queries [Deep Queries](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-09-24-atomic-writes-and-more.html). You an also search here of stack overflow for examples as well. I don't know what  your platform is and the examples on the website have different ones - I do MacOS Swift or Obj-C. Let me know if you need something in those after you review the blog post.

Comment: thanks for that. I've just read the post and other 'deep query' question on SO but I still can't see how to use a deep query to do this (boxes don't have any reference to the project/s they belong in, is that what you were thinking?). I'm using the JavaScript SDK.

Comment: @DavidGilbertson Check out my answer - as you can see, the projects know what boxes they have and the boxes know which projects they belong to. You may want to alter your current Firebase structure to match what I suggested to make it work. You would then use a deep query on the boxes node to retrieve the boxes for a particular project.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I don't think what you're saying is possible. How do I deep query to say *give me all boxes where the box's belongs_to_project list contains an item with key "project_37"*? I don't see anywhere in the docs that describes a query like that (particularly the 'contains' part). It would be great if this was actually possible, is it in the docs? If you could put a code sample in your answer (swift is fine, I'll work it out) that would be great.

Comment: we got there in the end! That's perfect, thanks. I've added the JavaScript version to my question.

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I'm happy with my approach, using `Promise.all` to respond once all the individual 'queries' are returned:

I've changed my approach to use promises, then call `Promise.all()` to indicate that all the data is ready to send.

```
const projectId = req.params.projectId;

const boxPromises = [];

const projectBoxesRef = db
  .child('data/projects')
  .child(projectId)
  .child('boxes');

function getBox(boxSnapshot) {
  boxPromises.push(db
    .child('data/boxes')
    .child(boxSnapshot.key())
    .once('value')
    .then(boxSnapshot => boxSnapshot.val())
  );
}

projectBoxesRef.on('child_added', getBox);

projectBoxesRef.once('value', () => {
  projectBoxesRef.off('child_added', getBox);

  Promise.all(boxPromises).then(boxes => res.json(boxes));
});
```